# how to find prime numbers function - loop without getting timeout error?

Tags: c, for-loop, primes

im writing a code that return '1' when its prime number , and '0' when its not
i used for loop , and i keep getting "TIMEOUT ERROR " when i run it .
for example :Running test: IsPrimeNumber(59000000623)  --  Passed
Running test: IsPrimeNumber(59094001973)  --  Failed: Timeout

thats my code (i tried to replace unsigned long with long long int without succsses)

```
int IsPrimeNumber(unsigned long  n )
{
 int  count = 0;
 unsigned long  i;
for(i=2; i<=n/2; ++i)
{
    if(n%i==0)
    {
        count=1;
        break;
    }
}


if (count==1)
    return 0;
else
    return 1;    
}
```

Comment: Hint: what happens after sqrt(n) ?

Comment: `59000000623` is divisible by `83`, so your loop reaches that quite fast. `59094001973` is a prime number, so it has to run through the whole loop.

Comment: Hint 2: do you need to check even numbers?

Comment: @jabberwocky no , prime numbers

Comment: @proran so how could this help you to make your code faster?

Comment: I think that my code stops on the limit of 'long int' -the max range of it - and i cant make it accept bigger values (long long int )